# Reverse sorting order of a list only by modifying the method called by the Comparator

Tags: algorithm, sorting

Let's say I have the following scenario

```java
static record AClass(String name, int id) {     
    public String getValueForComparator() {
        return this.name;
    }
}

static class UnmodifiableAComparator implements Comparator<AClass>{
    @Override
    public int compare(AClass o1, AClass o2) {
        return o1.getValueForComparator().compareTo(o2.getValueForComparator());
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<AClass> myList = Arrays.asList(
            new AClass("C", 1),
            new AClass("A", 3),
            new AClass("B", 2));
    myList.sort(new UnmodifiableAComparator());
    for (AClass obj: myList) {
        System.out.println(obj);
    }
}
```

It will sort myList by AClass.name descending into

```
AClass[name=A, id=3]
AClass[name=B, id=2]
AClass[name=C, id=1]
```

Is there a way to make the above code sort myList by AClass.name ascending instead, only by modifying "getValueForComparator()"?

If getValueForComparator() were to return int instead, the obvious way would be to return the inverted value instead:

```java
public int getValueForComparator() {
    return this.id;
}

can be modified to 

public int getValueForComparator() {
    return -this.id;
}
```

with the same spirit, I can invert the string

```java
public String getValueForComparator() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (char c: this.name.toCharArray()) {
        char cInvert =  (char) (256 - c);
        sb.append(cInvert);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

This seem to work. But is there a catch to this solution, or edge case that will not handled properly? I am thinking of unicode or encoding-related issue, but am not really familiar with internalities of String.

Comment: Asking whether a solution is the best is off topic here. If you have a *problem*, then please focus your question on that. Also, please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Why the arbitrary restriction that you have to modify `getValueForComparator`, rather than modifying `UnmodifiableAComparator`, or adding a new `ADescendingComparator`? The *point* of having a comparator separate from the class is that you don't need such hacks and can instead pass a proper `Comparator`.

Comment: Long story short, it is because I am upgrading a framework our project is using. The "getValueForComparator()" is actually a method from interface exposed by the framework that does something else, and just happen to be used as value for a sorting by the framework.

Comment: (cont.) 
The new version of the framework reverses the way AClass was sorted. This sorting is really just used for the internally in the framework,and in ideal world, the order it is sorted shouldn't matter. But our project accidentally depends on this, and the cost to remove this dependency could be high. That's why I was considering this "cheap hack".

Comment: It certainly wouldn't work on UTF-8, but your original probably didn't either so maybe you don't care.

Comment: Please add a tag indicating which language is being used.